# freshplanet push notification ANE makes my app crash when gets notification

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, push-notification, ane

My Android crashes when I get notification with this ANE

https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification

What can I do to fix it?
Have anyone tried this ANE file on Android?

I tried this one 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6nEmghkuTbZMWc4VGw5alp5Zms&usp=sharing

I can run it with no errors, but I need to rebuild the ANE file so that I can make some changes on it.
The second one doesn`t work when my Android app is in foreground!

Also when I try to rebuild it, I get this warning in "ant" compiling process:
..... android\temp\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with                                                                                                                 -source 1.6

Although it says that "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" at the end, the built ANE file does not work at all, and it keeps crashing my app when a notification receives.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and bring relevant code into the question.

Comment: actually I tried this ANE https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6nEmghkuTbZMWc4VGw5alp5Zms&usp=sharing  from https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification/issues/61  and finally I was able to run the ANE file, but I'm willing to rebuild the ANE file ... let me Edit the question. OK ;)

Answer (score 1):

try use this notification ANE for Adobe air ,
it's new , brilliant and support ios&Android from OneSignal Company
http://marpies.com/portfolio/onesignal-ane/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, is it a free service? and Can I send notifications from my server based on PHP code or I should use their website/dashboard? I need a solution to be able to send notification via PHP from my own website to my Android/iOS app made by Adobe Flash (AIR).

Comment: Yes its a free service, and you send your notification from their dashboard , but i'm not sure to send notification via PHP, test it  and if you get the answer please say here

Comment: Thank you for information, but I somehow did get the ANE to work.

Comment: also you can use this ANE form myflashlabs [link](http://www.myflashlabs.com/product/local-notification-ane-adobe-air-native-extension/)